# nftables.conf - file permissions

Tags: server, 22.04, chmod, nftables

after the plain installation of nftables (ubuntu server 22.04) the permissions of the /etc/nftables.conf file are set to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x). i cannot believe that it's necessary that anyone has read and execute rights. so:
*what are the correct minimum rights for nftables?*

```
chmod 644 /etc/nftables.conf [?]
```

i looked through the web and [man pages](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page), but couldn't find a trusted answer.

Comment: The file is owned by `root`, and it is not executable, so I don't see any problems

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/nftables.conf`  has `755` permissions by default.

It is owned by the `root` user.

This means that only `root` user can write to this file. Everyone else can only read and execute it.

It is a text configuration file, so it is not executable. It doesn't make any practical difference how you set permissions `755` or `644`.

But `644` looks more appropriate.

Comment: thx, but still, does everyone needs read access? I could imagine that's a security risk.

Comment: Yes, other users need read access, like to all other `.conf` files in etc. There is nothing secret there.